# Table with fixed header, scrollable body and no limit on width/height and not fixed column widths?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, html-table

I'm trying to make a table like this (found the code on here) but with 10 times more columns that continue outside of the browser window, creating a horizontal scroll. See my example crops the table and adjusts to 100% width.

Is this possible?

https://codepen.io/seabasse/pen/yXLKWJ

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #efefef;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  border-top: 41px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 41px solid transparent;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td + td {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

td, th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
}

thead tr th,
tfoot tr td {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

thead tr th div,
tfoot tr td div {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

thead tr th div {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

tfoot tr td div {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

tfoot tr td div.c1,
thead tr th div.c1 {
  background: violet;
}

tfoot tr td div.c2,
thead tr th div.c2 {
  background: green;
}

tfoot tr td div.c3,
thead tr th div.c3 {
  background: yellow;
}

thead tr th div {
  top: 0;
}

tfoot tr td div {
  bottom: 0;
}

thead tr th:first-child div,
tfoot tr td:first-child div {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Header one *leads the width* (case 1)
            <div class="c1">
              Header one *leads the width* (case 1)
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Header two
            <div class="c2">
              Header two
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Header three
            <div class="c3">
              Header three
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three [first]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three [LATEST]</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Footer one
            <div class="c1">
              Footer one
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            Footer two
            <div class="c2">Footer two</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            Footer three *leads the width* (case 3)
            <div class="c3">Footer three *leads the width* (case 3)</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I need to remove the overflow on the wrapper, but I'm still having problem with the table body not going outside of the window. It seems like it sets an `overflow-x: scroll;` automatically when only `overflow-y: scroll;` is set (when shrinking the window width, if that makes any sense).

Comment: Ideas? Thank you!